# How do I wire up an IAspectProvider so that PostSharp will use it?

Tags: c#, aop, postsharp

I've written a class in C# that implements PostSharp's `IAspectProvider` interface. What I don't understand is what I'm supposed to do with it now that I have it. I can't seem to find any documentation on PostSharp's site that tells me what to do with this class once it's written.

Does PostSharp just automatically find this class because it's derived from `IAspectProvider` and use it? Or is there a link available to a page that I have thus far been unable to find?

FWIW, the class is provided below. (`MethodTracingAspect` is our custom aspect we're using for training.)

```
namespace LoggingSample
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    using PostSharp.Aspects;

    internal class ProviderAspect : IAspectProvider
    {
        public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
        {
            var type = (Type) targetElement;

            return type.GetMethods()
                       .Where(m => type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IReportBuilder)) 
                                   && m.IsPublic 
                                   && m.Name == "Execute")
                       .Select(m => new AspectInstance(targetElement, 
                                                       new MethodTracingAspect()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PostSharp, a class implementing `IAspectProvider` is just another aspect and you need to apply it to target elements in the same way as any other aspect. So, usually, your aspect provider class should also derive from one of the attribute classes. Then you can apply it as an attribute to target element and this element will be passed into `ProvideAspects` method during build time.

In your specific example you can derive from the `TypeLevelAspect`, because you expect your `targetElement` to be a type.

An example of the aspect provider is available on this documentation page: http://doc.postsharp.net/example-dataattributes

Example of aspect usage:

```
// Aspect class
[Serializable]
public class ProviderAspect : TypeLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Apply to a single type
[ProviderAspect]
public class TargetClass : IReportBuilder
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

// Apply to many types
[assembly: ProviderAspect (AttributeTargetTypes="OurCompany.OurApplication.Reports.*")]
```

You can find more information about applying aspect to your code on this documentation page: http://doc.postsharp.net/applying-aspects

P.S. We will also review our documentation page for aspect providers and add the information about usage.

Comment: I think I understand most of this (as the original article I found states, some mental gymnastics are involved). However, I am still unclear about what to do with the class once it's written. The linked sample you've provided still only provides an implementation of `IAspectProvider`. Does that aspect need to be explicitly referenced from `AssemblyInfo.cs`? Do I need to decorate a type or two with the aspect? Or will PostSharp automatically find the provider at compile time, and make use of it, because it derives from `IAspectProvider`?

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer with an example. Sorry, that the first answer was not completely clear.

Comment: also you don't need assemblyinfo to provide aspects. One example is decorate a class with an IAspectProvider aspect and it will add aspects too all methods in the class (using reflection).  You just need any entry point into your code for your IAspectProviders to run

Comment: Thanks, @AlexD. That answers my question perfectly.